# Installed Ubuntu, Windows 10 gone

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

While installing ubuntu I got a warning that the Windows 10 installation was in BIOS mode instead of UEFI, so I hit cancel.

After that the installation resumed and I assumed it had adapted. I chose the alongside Windows option, everything worked as intended but after rebooting Windows wasn't an option in GRUB. The Windows Partition is still there, but in unsafe mode.

It might also be worth mentioning that the system refused to boot a BIOS mode install-drive even after making sure the BIOS was configured accordingly.

Highest priority is restoring the ability to boot into Windows.

Second priority is setting up a working Ubuntu installation alongside Windows while maintaining this ability.

Comment: You can only easily dual boot if both Ubuntu & Windows in same boot mode. So you needed to install Ubuntu in BIOS mode, if Windows is BIOS. But how you boot is how it knows which way to install. You cannot in middle change. If you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode it may have converted drive to gpt and Windows BIOS mode cannot boot from gpt only UEFI. And you cannot convert Windows to UEFI without total reinstall. May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Install drives in BIOS mode don't boot for whatever reason. I know those things already. What I don't know is how to fix Windows and how to get a BIOS mode install medium to boot.

Comment: Do not know if Windows is even there still. Post link, otherwise difficult to know what to suggest.  As far as booting in BIOS mode, you must have UEFI Secure Boot off and may still have to turn on allow USB boot or USB port settings, check UEFI/BIOS settings.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.